# What is the difference between "thermal" and "thermic"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Definition of thermic by Google:

> adjective
>   1.
>   relating to heat.
>
> ***e.g.*** thermic effect

Definition of thermal by Google:

> adjective
>   1.
>   relating to heat.
>
> ***e.g.*** thermal conductivity

Honestly, I also don't really understand what is *thermal* other than the vague definition ***"relating to heat"***

Answer (score 2):

"Thermal" is far more common as a separate word for concepts related to heat:  *thermal blanket, thermal reaction, thermal physics, thermal depolymerization, thermal power plant*, etc.

You will see "thermic" used as a suffix in many scientific terms that relate to heat:  *endothermic, exothermic, hypothermic, exothermic* and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. Although according to [corpus of contemporary american English](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), I think you should use the word `Thermal`, because `thermic` is very unusual and has been used rarely.